# Jquery: Changing a value on a page as you check and uncheck checkboxe

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller

I have this line of code that exist in a partial view. Jquery code resides in the index page hosting the partial view

```
        <div class="paythisamountbtn">@Html.ActionLink(T("Pay This Amount"), "InvoiceCheckout", null, new { @target = "InvoiceCheckout", @class = "amebtn" }): @String.Format("{0:C}", Model.TotalDue)</div>
```

I have a checkbox on every row of data. This is all within a webgrid. Here is what it looks like below

```
        @{
            var gridColumns = new List<WebGridColumn>();

            gridColumns.Add(grid.Column(format: (item) => 
                {
                    var s = "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"InvoiceNumber\" id=\"IN" +  item.InvoiceNumber.ToString() + "\" value=\"" + item.InvoiceNumber.ToString() + "|" + item.AmountDue + "\"";
                    if (item.IsSelected) {
                        s += "checked=\"true\"";
                    }
                    s+= "/>";
                    return s;
                }
                    , style: "box"));

        ...
        ...
        ...
        }

        function SetViewSelected(c) {   
                var s = 0;
                for (i = 0; i < $("input[name='InvoiceNumber']:checked").length; i++) {
                    invoice_details = $("input[name='InvoiceNumber']:checked")[i].value;
                    invoice_amount = invoice_details.split("|")[1];
                    s += parseFloat(invoice_amount);
                }
                alert(s);
                //$('.paythisamountbtn').val(s);
        }
```

As I check and uncheck the checkboxes, I want to be able to show the total on the line below as they change. At the moment the alert(s) gets me the new total

```
        <div class="paythisamountbtn">@Html.ActionLink(T("Pay This Amount"), "InvoiceCheckout", null, new { @target = "InvoiceCheckout", @class = "amebtn" }): @String.Format("{0:C}", Model.TotalDue)</div>
```

I tried doing $('.paythisamountbtn').val(s); but the totaldue does not change as I check and uncheck the check boxes.

How can I do this please?

Answer (score 0):

Use `.text` for a `div`

```
$('.paythisamountbtn').text(s)
```

Comment: I need to keep the initial total value that displays when the page loads. I dont get this total anymore.

Comment: This code won't affect the value on page load, the problem for that is elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

To update the attribute value what you must do is the following:

```
   $('.paythisamountbtn').text(parseInt($('.paythisamountbtn').text())+5);
```

To update the value each time you click one of the checkboxes you could do something like this:

```
$('#checkbox1').change(function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        UpdateValueNow();
    }     
});
```

Comment: I have an initial total that is loaded when this page loads. The value now has disappeared.